# Homeomorphism envolving the sphere $S^1$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I need to prove that for every $c>0$, the set $H=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 -z^2 = c\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}.$

I know that $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$. Then my idea is to find a contínuous function $f$, that is, $f: \mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that the graphic is $H$. Then $H$ is homeomorphic to domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea is a reasonable one, but it's probably easier to prove this by directly constructing continuous maps from $H$ to $S^1\times \Bbb{R}$ and vice versa.

Note that if $c>0$, then $x^2+y^2-z^2=c$ means that $x^2+y^2=c+z^2$. So for any fixed value of $z$, the points satisfying the equation lie on a circle or radius $\sqrt{c+z^2}$.

Can you use this to construct a continuous map directly from $H$ to $S^1\times \Bbb{R}$? What is the inverse map? Is it also continuous?

**Edit:** Further details

Given $(x,y,z)\in H$, let $r=\sqrt{c+z^2}$, and send $(x,y,z)$ to 
$((x/r,y/r),z)$. Since $r$ is continuous and nonzero, this is a continuous map from $H$ to $S^1\times \Bbb{R}$. What is the inverse function?

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you help me one more time?

Comment: Sure I'll add a couple more details :) (Added them now)

Comment: oooooooo it's easy, how I didn't see that? thank you guy :)